# Why does hot water in a hot flask later cool?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, dissipation

What make hot water cool in thermos flask since it doesn’t release energy?

Comment: Because residing in a thermoflask, water releases thermal energy very slowly.

Comment: A thermos is not perfect.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How long can a thermal flask hold heat?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/282073/)